# PHP compare HTML characters array Solution

Tags: php, html

I got a value in `$arrNew[4]`, I want to run a foreach loop on `$arrNew` and
check if a value is equal to `$arrNew[4]`.

I want to compare `$arrNew` with the value in `$arrNew[4]`.

The problem is, that value isn't there most of the times, so i
want it as a string so i can use it on other parts.
But if I `echo $arrNew[4]` out I get `"vrij &nbsp  &nbsp  "`

It isn't the same as in `$arrNew[4]` because I can't do `$forNew == "vrij &nbsp  &nbsp  "`
but I can do `$forNew == $arrNew[4]`

How should I do this ?

Any help is appreciated :)

```
foreach ($arrNew as $forNew)   
{           
   $forCount = $forCount + 1 ;
   if($forNew == $arrNew[4])
   {
      echo "Vrij: ".$arrOld[$forCount] ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: I already did that: array diff outputs "vrij &nbsp  &nbsp  " but if I do $forNew === "vrij &nbsp  &nbsp  " it doesn't return TRUE....

Comment: Just to make sure that I am clear--we are comparing an array with a vlaue from within that SAME array, right?  Would you mind posting your test data (i.e. the contents of both arrays)?

Comment: My bad for being a little bit vague, I wan't to compare the array to what is currently in $arrNew[4]. I want wat is in $arrNew[4] to a string so I can create the if statement without the need of the value sitting in $arrNew[4] cause it isn't always there. But if I echo out $arrNew[4] it isn't the same as what is actually in $arrNew[4]. Due to some special character conversion that takes place I think.

Comment: ..and I gather that the converstion happens with print_r(), too?

Comment: Yeah with print_r() I get: "vrij &nbsp  &nbsp  "

Comment: okay...let's try another approach.  Have you tried 'in_array'?