# PHP Array special value Solution

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP compare HTML characters array Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504735/php-compare-html-characters-array-solution)

I got a value stored in `$arrNew[4]`, I want to
check if the value currently stored in `$arrNew[4]` is equal to another value.

The problem is, the value in arrNew[4]  isn't there most of the times, so i
want it as a string so i can use it on other parts.

example `$string = "text"`
I want "text". The same goes with $arrNew[4]

But if I `echo $arrNew[4]` out I get `"vrij &nbsp  &nbsp  "`

It isn't the same as in `$arrNew[4]` because I can't do `$forNew == "vrij &nbsp  &nbsp  "` it doesn't equal TRUE but `$forNew == $arrNew[4]` does.

So how should I get the value stored in $arrNew[4] to a string,
without it being changed. (probably cause of special characters?)

How should I do this ?

Any help is appreciated :)

```
foreach ($arrNew as $forNew)   
{           
   $forCount = $forCount + 1 ;
   if($forNew == $arrNew[4])
   {
      echo "Vrij: ".$arrOld[$forCount] ;
   }
}
```

Comment: tried explaining it better in the main post. Thanks

Comment: Try using [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: Thanks Robik, didn't work. Outputs to: "vrij &nbsp  &nbsp  " I still can't do $arrNew[4]="vrij &nbsp  &nbsp  "

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, the value in arrNew[4] isn't there most of the times,

You should explain why.

> so i want it as a string so i can use it on other parts.

Why do you think that not having it as a string will not allow you to use it elseehere, please explain.

> But if I echo $arrNew[4] out I get "vrij &nbsp &nbsp "

Echoing a variable and getting &nbsp in the browser is sure there is an important piece of information that you don't display, please show it (sounds like something related html specialchar).

> ```
> It isn't the same as in $arrNew[4] because I can't do $forNew ==
> ```
>
> "vrij &nbsp &nbsp " it doesn't equal TRUE but $forNew == $arrNew[4]

It seems that apart from php you have some work to do on expressing your self, describing and presenting a problem in an understoodable way.

> So how should I get the value stored in $arrNew[4] to a string,
>   without it being changed.

Just  undo whatever you did on storage, I suspect it doesn't get a value assigned in a trvial way but insted through an html specialchar function.

Finally take serious consideration on writing good question, put your self in others position.